# An affordable way to use multiple Delayed::Job queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, web-hosting, heroku, delayed-job

I have a Ruby on Rails app that needs process many background jobs simultaneously: anywhere from 5-6 at a time to up to 50-60 at a time depending on the time of day. Right now my app is running on Heroku, which charges $.05/hour per worker, regardless of how much CPU or memory the worker is using. This is costing me a boatload each month... up to $1200/mo. Are there any hosts that will allow me to do what I'm doing for significantly cheaper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to my own server was the way to go. I'm paying under $300/month for a machine that can run 40 workers easily. The downside is having to learn about server administration, but it's not too bad.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a massively parallel worker system that you only pay for by the second (so you really only pay for the time your worker is working), check out SimpleWorker at http://www.simpleworker.com . I bet it would cost you a small fraction of what it cost on Heroku and doing it yourself.

We are also available as a [Heroku add-on](http://support.simpleworker.com/kb/getting-started/simpleworker-on-heroku).